# Running uuidd automatically on startup on Ubuntu 13.10 server?

Tags: services, uuid

I am running the 13.10 Ubuntu server edition on which I have installed SAP's Netweaver Gateway 2.0 trial. This requires the UUID daemon to be running.

Whenever I start up the system and run `uuidd` as root (because it is not running), it gives the following error:

```
Failed to open/create /var/run/uuidd/uuidd.pid: No such file or directory
```

I then have to create `/var/run/uuidd` and give write permission to all, after which I can start uuidd.

I previously ran 11.04, and did not have this problem, so I assume `uuidd` was running by default (the SAP system never complained, but it does complain if it's not running).

Is there a way to get uuidd to start on boot, maybe an init script I can copy from somewhere? Part of the problem also is that /var/run/uuidd needs to be created each time.